# How to conditionally enable launchScript() inside bootJar?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to setup a conditional build process.

The following code works, but I need to specify the parameter on the command line, while It should be good to define two separate task to do that.

```
bootJar {
    if (project.hasProperty("exec")) {
      launchScript()
    }
}
```

Is there a way to execute the bootJar or another custom task to enable/disable the launchScript()?

For example, how i can define the task bootJarExecutable that acts as the standard bootJar but with the launchScript ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another task that just configures your `bootJar` task when executed:

```
task bootJarExecutable {
    finalizedBy bootJar
    doFirst {
        bootJar.launchScript()
    }
}
```

However, this only works if you need either the one `.jar` or the other in one invocation, but not both. In this case, you would need to create another [`BootJar`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/api/org/springframework/boot/gradle/tasks/bundling/BootJar.html) task and configure it on your own.

Comment: Thanks. I create another BootJar task.